# Does Google Admob need update for ipv6-only on iOS?

Tags: ios, admob, ipv6

iOS Jun APP need support IPV6-only, My game don't support network.

But I add an admob ads. Admob offical don't notice neither support ipv6 or not.

Does it cause problem ?

Comment: You'll have to ask them... We can't look into someone else's code

Comment: @zszen any update?

Comment: yes, but don't mention ipv6 in update infomation. I think it supported.